# Problem Importing Excel File into Access via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a multi-user Access Form that will essentially be open for most of the day on several peoples computers. On this form, I've created a button that will import an excel spreadsheet via VBA. The code is:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE ExcelTable.* FROM ExcelTable;"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ExcelTable", "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\MyTable.xlsx", True, "Data!A6:DB" & numberofrows
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

This code imports the data fine. However, users will frequently need to update the spreadsheet throughout the day. There are 2 problems that I am frequently running into:

1. If a user attempts to overwrite the original spreadsheet with an updated version, they receive an error message "Cannot access read-only document".
2. If the user attempts to open the spreadsheet, they receive the error message that the excel file is locked for editing.

I was under the impression that by running the above VBA code, the user is importing a static table (not a linked table), meaning that once the table is imported into Access, it's no longer referencing the original Excel file.

How do I get around these error messages?

The users will need to update the excel file several times throughout the day and right now, everyone has to completely exit Access in order to access the original excel file.

Comment: The issue must be caused by something else. I can open and even update the Excel file after an import, then run the import again, and the updated data are read. Also, have the file opened in Excel and run the import.

Comment: *If the user attempts to open the spreadsheet, they receive the error message that the excel file is locked for editing*. That is because Access runs an instance of Excel.

Comment: The fact that multiple users are possibly overwriting and/or opening the spreadsheet, have you not considered that they may be trying to do that at the same time?  You have not shared anything about how you avoid such conflicts with the shared file, so the default assumption is that it is likely another user locking the file and not necessarily Access.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had problems with Access and files locks on database and non-database files residing on a basic Linux NAS (Network Attached Storage) device.  It was a 3rd party system and I'm not a linux guru, so I never solved the problem despite it being in "Windows sharing mode".  As soon as I moved the files to a Windows Server (and even a Windows 10 Home machine), the locking problems did not exist.

Comment: C Perkins- It's highly unlikely that multiple users will be trying to import the file at the same time. Though multiple users work in the database, it's only 5-6 people and they all work next to each other, so there is a level of communication as to who is importing the file. Also, all files are stored on either Windows 7  or Windows 10.